# Who is responsible for software licensing in ITIL?

Tags: licensing

In a standard ICT Department who is responsible for managing software licenses?

I would start by saying that the ICT Manager is accountable for it.  But who gets the responsibility, using ITIL as a standard model for an ICT department would the Service Delivery Manager or Development Manager?

The Service Delivery Manager needs to keep things running, but when moving forward with new versions of software does the Development Manager get controlling vote in what to purchase?  As it's not just about delivering the service it's about improving it.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Asset_Management and also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library#7._Software_Asset_Management

Comment: Thanks for this, I've completed the ITIL foundation and service design course so I'm aware of asset management and the service catalogue.  But I'm wondering more about the real world implementation in a small to medium sized business who normally does it?

Answer (score 0):

In our Org, it has been the finance dept.
They take care of purchasing, tracking and reporting on software license use.
They are responsible for reporting to auditors.
They report to the CIO and CFO who are (I think) actually legally responsible.